# Azure file storage putRange operation fails with 416: InvalidHeaderValue (Content-Length)

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk, http-content-length

I'm using the Azure SDK to perform basic operations on an Azure files storage. In order to support larger file uploads I support chunked uploads, so I'm calling:

`$storage->createFileFromContent(...)` on the first chunk and

`$storage->putFileRange(...)` on all the following.

The first request works fine and the file is filled with inside the first range specified. The second and following requests however fail with the error:

```
Code: 416
Value: The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.
```

Here are my specified headers for the first request:

```
{
  ["x-ms-range"]=>"bytes=0-2999999"
  ["content-length"]=>3000000
  ["x-ms-write"]=>"Update"
}
```

Actual size of the stream: **3000000**

And for the second request:

```
{
  ["x-ms-range"]=>"bytes=3000000-5999999"
  ["content-length"]=>3000000
  ["x-ms-write"]=>"Update"
}
```

Actual size of the stream: **3000000**

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?? I also tried to adjust the Range to something like 300000-6000000, but then I get this error:

"Code: 400
Value: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format. >> Content-Length"

**Could this be caused by a wrong configuration of the storage in Azure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are not uploading the ranges to a file that is actually 6000000 byte long. Put Range operation will not expand the size of the file for you implicitly. You need to explicitly call [`SetFileProperties`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/1afdf1c788a729ed486a6ef1c2e74d3db7b199b9/azure-storage-file/src/File/Internal/IFile.php#L785) to resize the file first.

`$storage->createFileFromContent(...)` will set the file size as the same size to the content, so it is very likely not to be 6000000 byte.

Also, if there is a mismatch in range and the content length, e.g. in your case where range specifies 3000001 bytes while content length is 3000000 bytes, a mentioned 400 will be returned by the server.